# Declaring a vector of objects as a member of another class

Tags: c++, class, vector

Hi I'm looking to declare a vector of objects as a member of another class but I'm not quite sure how to do this.  And also am I filling the vector correctly in the last function?

This is the class that I want to create a vector of

```
class AggregatedQuoteType
{
    public:
        AggregatedQuoteType(double price, unsigned long volume);
        double get_price() const;
        unsigned long get_volume() const;
        unsigned long get_number_of_orders() const;
    private:
        double newPrice;
        unsigned long newVolume;
};
```

and I want the vector to be a member of this class

```
class OrderBook
{
    public:

        OrderBook ();

        void open (double tick_size, double tolerance, std::ostream &log);

        void close ();

        unsigned long submit_order (double price, unsigned long volume);

    private:

        PriceType order_tick_size;

        PriceType order_tolerance;


};
```

Here is what I have so far for my function

```
unsigned long OrderBook::submit_order (double price, unsigned long volume)
{
    AggregatedQuoteType newQuote(price, volume);
    unsigned long number_of_orders = newQuote.get_number_of_orders();
    std::vector<AggregatedQuoteType> newMyOrder;

    if(price > 0 && volume > 0){
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < number_of_orders; i++){
            newMyOrder.push_back(newQuote);
        }
    }

    return 0u;
}
```

Any help would be useful.

Comment: Just like with any other member. Put this in the class definition `std::vector<AggregatedQuoteType> vec;`

Comment: What is submit_order supposed to do? It currently adds number_of_orders copies of newQuote to the vector. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Without fully understanding how submit_order() works, I think you need something like this:

```
   class OrderBook
    {
        public:
            OrderBook ();
            void open (double tick_size, double tolerance, std::ostream &log);
            void close ();
            unsigned long submit_order (double price, unsigned long volume);   
        private:
            PriceType order_tick_size;
            PriceType order_tolerance;
            std::vector<AggregatedQuoteType> quotes_;  
    };


unsigned long OrderBook::submit_order (double price, unsigned long volume)
{
    AggregatedQuoteType newQuote(price, volume);
    unsigned long number_of_orders = newQuote.get_number_of_orders();

    if(price > 0 && volume > 0){
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < number_of_orders; i++){
            quotes_.push_back(newQuote);
        }
    }
    return 0u;
}
```